# Can a Netgear Wireless Cable Modem Gateway (CG814GCMR) be used as a wireless bridge?

Tags: router, bridge

Can a Netgear Wireless Cable Modem Gateway (CG814GCMR) be used as a wireless bridge?

Comment: Do you mean you want it to make a wireless link to an existing AP/"wireless router"/"wireless bridge", and bridge traffic from that wireless link to wired Ethernet machines plugged into the CG814GCMR?

Answer (score 0):

Assign your device an IP address (that exists on the same subnet as your network), turn off your DHCP server and/or NAT functions, disable any firewalls, and hook it up to your network with it broadcasting wirelessly.

It should work.

Comment: That's how to make it a simple bridging Access Point that bridges frames between a set of individual wireless clients and devices on the LAN ports. It can be context-dependent, but most times someone says "wireless bridge", they're talking about creating a wireless point-to-point link to bridge traffic between two wired LANs, which is not what your answer currently covers. I've asked for clarification from @Vivek.